# How to share JWT token between sub domain A and sub domain B both hosted on Firebase using Nuxt?

Tags: firebase, cookies, jwt, nuxt.js, subdomain

My main domain is igeddit.ca.

I have sub domain A: elearning.igeddit.ca
and
sub domain B: technical.igeddit.ca

The eLearning site is where users sign in and are verified and authorized by Firebase and receive their token. I save the token as a jwt cookie.

My understanding was that if I formatted the cookie in the following way, then I could share the cookie I created on sub domain A (elearning.iggedit.ca) with sub domain B (technical.igeddit.ca):

```
domain: '.igeddit.ca', path: "/", sameSite: 'strict', secure: true
```

And, I thought it would work because I could view the cookie that I created on sub domain A when I inspected sub domain B:

[image: cooking created on sub domain A elearning.igeddit.ca]

[image: viewing cookie on sub domain B technical.igeddit.ca]

However, the token will not load on sub domain B. The following error is displayed:

[image: 404 error loading cookie]

It seems I have everything right up until I load the cookie. Could the issue be that Google Firebase sites are prevented from sharing cookies. I read in a few places that Firebase only allows a specific session cookie that has to be written via Firebase functions...is this the case. Appreciate any insights.

Comment: Are you sure that path exists because the error code says  404? I can see the cookie in the request.

Comment: Thanks @Dharmaraj. I changed the path it was uppercase and was redirecting from LMS to lms. The previous path was technical.igeddit.ca/LMS and I changed it to technical.igeddit.ca/lms/. I no longer get the 404 error. The status code is now 200 but I'm still not able to parse the cookie. When I run the exact same code on localhost everything works great as expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of research, Google Firebase sites are prevented from sharing cookies with one another except for a session cookie: __session. I am posting a follow up question to this one because there seems to be a lot of confusion re. the __session cookie; probably because there are differences between Firebase v8 vs v9.

Comment: If you want to know how share a __session cookie in Nuxt using Firebase v9, see this follow up thread. It has all the answers: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76725320/sharing-firebase-session-cookie-in-nuxt-between-sub-domains