# Sharing Firebase __session cookie in Nuxt between sub domains

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication, nuxt.js, session-cookies

Summary: To get a more detailed idea of what I'm trying to do, [read my previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76684730/12191011). So briefly I'm trying to create a Firebase __session cookie on my first site (elearning.igeddit.ca) and then sharing and reading that __session cookie with my second site (technical.igeddit.ca)

So I'm using `auth.onAuthStateChanged` when a user signs into elearning.igeddit.ca with their email and password. I'm using onAuthStateChanged to trigger the cookie creation on log in.

```
//...
import Cookies from "js-cookie";
//...
async onAuthStateChangedAction(vuexContext, authUser) {
        if (!authUser) {
            console.log("removing session cookie")
            Cookies.remove('__session')
        } else {
            console.log("adding session cookie")
            let idToken = authUser.getIdToken();
            console.log("idToken: ", idToken);
            Cookies.set('__session', idToken, { expires: 0.04166667 })
        }
    },
```

As you can see by the picture of the console.log, the cookie is being set - at least I'm assuming it's being set correctly. So all seems to be good on the writing side of the __session cookie.
[image: session cookie console]

When I launch technical.igeddit.ca in localhost (I'm testing both sites in a localhost environment btw) I can see the __session cookie:
[image: session cookie at technical.igeddit.ca]

The problem I'm now having is that I still can't read the __session cookie on technical.igeddit.ca

```
//...
import Cookies from "js-cookie";
//....
nuxtServerInit({ req }) {
        console.log("nuxt init...")
        const sessionCookie = Cookies.get('__session')
        console.log("sessionCookie: ", sessionCookie);

        if (!sessionCookie) {
            console.log("no cookie found...")
        } else {
            console.log("there's a session cookie...")
        }
    },
```

The logs return the following:
[image]
[image]

I'm obviously missing something. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the following lines:

```
console.log("adding session cookie")
let idToken = authUser.getIdToken();
console.log("idToken: ", idToken);
Cookies.set('__session', idToken, { expires: 0.04166667 });
```

Here, the `__session` cookie is defined with an expiry of 1h, but the value is set to `idToken` - a `Promise<string>` that will resolve to the ID token of the user.

To fix this, you need to move the set cookie logic inside of the `then` handler of the ID token Promise.

```js
console.log("adding session cookie")
authUser.getIdToken()
  .then((idTokenJWT) => {
    console.log("idToken: ", idTokenJWT); // TODO: Remove this line
    Cookies.set('__session', idTokenJWT, { expires: 0.04166667 });
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    // TODO: Handle errors
    console.error("Failed to get user ID token/update cookie: ", err);
  });
```

By default, `js-cookie` will set the cookie's domain [to the current domain](https://github.com/js-cookie/js-cookie/tree/b23b52b50c237db792f0121c41ff29216172cd46#user-content-domain) (in your case - `elearning.igeddit.ca`). To make this cookie work on other subdomains, you need to provide the domain argument:

```js
Cookies.set('__session', idTokenJWT, { expires: 0.04166667, domain: '.igeddit.ca' });
```

To remove the cookie later, you will also need to specify the same domain parameter:

```js
Cookies.remove('__session', { domain: '.igeddit.ca' });
```

---

You could also specify new values for the default attributes when you import the library:

```js
import RawCookies from "js-cookies";
const Cookies = RawCookies.withAttributes({ domain: '.igeddit.ca' });
// ...
Cookies.set('__session', idToken, { expires: 0.04166667 });
// ...
Cookies.remove('__session');
```

---

Instead of expiring the cookie in 1 hour, consider using the expiry of the token itself.

```js
console.log("adding session cookie")
authUser.getIdTokenResult() // note: API change
  .then((idToken) => {
    console.log("idToken: ", idToken); // TODO: Remove this line
    Cookies.set('__session', idToken.token, { expires: new Date(idToken.expirationTime) });
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    // TODO: Handle errors
    console.error("Failed to get user ID token/update cookie: ", err);
  });
```

Comment: Thanks @samthecodingman. That seems to have 1/2 of my problem solved...writing the __session cookie properly. When I decode the cookie I can see ""iss": "https://securetoken.google.com" at the top of it so that's got to be good. I still can't read the cookie on my other subdomain, so I'm obviously doing something wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you to @samthecodingman for answering the first part of my question: how to create a Firebase __session cookie. His solution is what I used to write my __session cookie.

The answer to part 2: Reading the session cookie.
The problem I then had was reading the __session cookie that I created at sign in at elearning.igeddit.ca with technical.igeddit.ca. Since I used `npm run generate` to create the static content for my firebase hosted site, `nuxtServerInit({ dispatch, commit }, { req }) {...` was unable to return a value for "req".

However all was not lost, follow [this link](https://books.google.ca/books?id=7vj3DwAAQBAJ&lpg=PA488&ots=SLrmZcMvpO&dq=nuxt%20req%20nuxtserverinit%20empty&pg=PA489#v=onepage&q=nuxt%20req%20nuxtserverinit%20empty&f=false) and create a plugin according to this author's excellent instructions. Here's the tl;dr. Mine looked like this:
in my store.js file:

```
import Cookies from "js-cookie";
import jwt_decode from "jwt-decode";

async nuxtClientInit({ dispatch }, ctx) {
        let sessionCookie = Cookies.get('__session');
        if (sessionCookie) {
            let decodedSessionCookie = jwt_decode(sessionCookie);
            if (decodedSessionCookie.aud == 'add_your_Specific_Aud_Value_Here') {
                dispatch("setAuthentication", true)
                dispatch("setUser", { email: `${decodedSessionCookie.email}` })
            }
        } else {
            window.onNuxtReady(() => { window.$nuxt.$router.push('/unregistered') })
        }
    },
```

The content of my 'nuxt-client-init.client.js' (the ".client." is the file name so that it only runs on the client side) plugin file looked like this:

```
export default async (ctx) => {
        await ctx.store.dispatch('nuxtClientInit', ctx)
}
```

And of course I registered my new plugin in nuxt.config.js like this:

`plugins: ['~/plugins/nuxt-client-init.client.js'],`

And that, my friends, is how you write and read a __session cookie that can be shared between sub domains hosted on Firebase. BTW I was using Firebase v9.